# Question about the trace map

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, solution-verification, trace-map

**Let k be a field and $f:M_n(k)\to k$ be linear transformation such that $f(AB)=f(BA)$ for all $A,B \in M_n(k)$. Show that f is a scalar multiple of trace map.**

I thought that it might be the determinant one but I'm not sure whether it is or not. I somehow have the intuition to solve the problem. I am searching for the guidance for this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use LaTeX to improve the formatting of your question. And what exactly is your question?

Comment: @the pointer can you please tell me how do I proceed to show the given map to be the scalar multiple of trace map.

Comment: The determinant function is not linear.

Comment: @user1551 can you please tell me how to think about the problem

Comment: What do you know about the trace map?

Comment: That is basically the linear map afaik.

Comment: Please elaborate! I didn't get the point properly.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Please tale a look at [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). You mention the determinant in your post, but do not explain what relation it has to your question. What have you tried? Did you try to prove it when $n=1$? When $n=2$? Did this suggest how to approach the problem for any $n$?

Comment: Consider using a basis for matrices i.e. 1 in a single cell, 0 everywhere else. Multiplying different such basis is it’s sufficient to show that off diagonal are 0 and on diagonal are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hints.* Denote by $E_{ij}$ the matrix whose only nonzero entry is a $1$ at the $(i,j)$-th position. For any pair of matrices $A$ and $B$, denote also by $[A,B]$ the *commutator* $AB-BA$.

1. Using the fact that $[E_{11},E_{12}]=E_{12}$ and $[E_{12},E_{21}]=E_{11}-E_{22}$, prove that the linear span of all commutators is the subspace of all traceless matrices.
2. Hence, by writing $M$ as $\left(M-\operatorname{tr}(M)E_{11}\right)+\operatorname{tr}(M)E_{11}$, prove that $f(M)=\operatorname{tr}(M)f(E_{11})$.

Comment: It is working. Thank you very much @user1551!

Comment: (As this suggests, what is underlying this result is that if $f,g:V\to k$ are functionals and $\ker g \subseteq \ker f$ then $f$ is a scalar multiple of $g$. In this case, $g=\mathrm{Tr}$ is the trace and its kernel consists of the subspace spanned by commutators.)